# Run VBA on specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have some excel code that works but only runs on active sheet. I want to specify exactly the sheet to input the data on. Here is the code:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & GetFile, Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$2"))
    .Name = "logexportdata"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

I tried changing the top line to this: With 
    Sheet("MigrationReport")..QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _

So its not just active sheet, I can run it on a specific sheet. But that gives me a compile error. How do I replace active sheet with the sheet name?

Comment: `sheets("name")` not `sheet`

Comment: try with Sheets("MigrationReport")...

Comment: And take the extra `.` out before `QueryTables`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MigrationReport")
    With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & GetFile, Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$2"))
        .Name = "logexportdata"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End With
```